# checkbox group get value of checked checkbox jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

Ive been searching for idea on how to get value of checkbox group but i need to the x and y for this so far what i have seen is only with one so i havent really found any relevant answer or idea to my problem so i will explain what i want to happend. In my X i have a number of columns namely `first quarter`,`second quester`,`third quarter` and `fourth quarter` in my Y i have names of students. And i also have an extra checkbox `option to add additional student`. I want to Check the check corresponding to names and quarter. I will used this to track down student who has taken the exam and who has not yet taken the exam. I am wondering how to group the the checkboxes in a way that when i check on it will automatically get the `student name` and `corresponding quarter`.

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td width="25%">
        <hr/>
    </td>
    <td width="15%">
        <center><span>1st Quarter</span>
        </center>
    </td>
    <td width="15%">
        <center><span>2nd Quarter</span>
        </center>
    </td>
    <td width="15%">
        <center><span>3rd Quarter</span>
        </center>
    </td>
    <td width="20%">
        <center><span>4th Quarter</span>
        </center>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span>Joe Smith</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <center>
            <input type="checkbox" name="studentrecord[]" />
        </center>
    </td>
    <td>
        <center>
            <input type="checkbox" name="studentrecord[]" />
        </center>
    </td>
    <td>
        <center>
            <input type="checkbox" name="studentrecord[]" />
        </center>
    </td>
    <td>
        <center>
            <input type="checkbox" name="studentrecord[]" />
        </center>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><span>John Smith</span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <center>
            <input type="checkbox" name="studentrecord[]" />
        </center>
    </td>
    <td>
        <center>
            <input type="checkbox" name="studentrecord[]" />
        </center>
    </td>
    <td>
        <center>
            <input type="checkbox" name="studentrecord[]" />
        </center>
    </td>
    <td>
        <center>
            <input type="checkbox" name="studentrecord[]" />
        </center>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Check [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/zf92c1cj/)

`Update`

```
$("input[name='student[]']:checked").map(function() {
    var $td = $(this).closest('td'),
        index = $td.index();
    valueToPush.push({
        Quarter: quarter.eq($td.index()).find('span').text().trim(),
        Student: $td.parent().find('td:first-child span').text().trim()
    });
});
```

Comment: please put jsFiddle example,so that your question is understandable.

Comment: what i want to happened is for example the user checks whatever check boxes for `joe smith`, I want to be able to record that `Joe Smith` plus the quarter with check

Comment: BTW: The <center> tag is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead. The <center> element was deprecated because it defines the presentation of its contents -- it doesn't describe its contents.

Comment: @IvanGerasimenko i will delete it right away. What is the cleanest way to make the checkbox get two values at the same time?like when i check the first check box for joe i should get `Joe Smith` and `1 Quarter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, 1 approach is to create an array of objects where each object represent a checkbox like

```
$(document).on('click', '#check', function() {    
    var $quarters = $('table tr:first-child td');
    var values = $("input[name='studentrecord[]']:checked").map(function(){
        var $td  = $(this).closest('td'), index = $td.index();
        return {
            quarter: $quarters.eq($td.index()).find('span').text().trim(),
            student: $td.parent().find('td:first-child span').text().trim()
        }
    }).get();
    console.log(values);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nccj6zbm/)

Note: No need to use event delegation if the button is present when script `$(document).on('click', '#check', function() {    })` is executed.

---

Another option is to store an array of quarters against each student like

```
$('#check').on('click', function () {
    var $quaters = $('table tr:first-child td'),
        students = {};
    $("input[name='studentrecord[]']:checked").each(function () {
        var $td = $(this).closest('td'),
            student = $td.parent().find('td:first-child span').text().trim();
        if (!students[student]) {
            students[student] = [];
        }
        students[student].push($quaters.eq($td.index()).find('span').text().trim())
    }).get();
    console.log(students);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nccj6zbm/3/)

Comment: Sir what do you mean in the note portion of the answer?

Comment: @HogRider `$('#check').on('click', function () {})` instead of `$(document).on('click', '#check', function() {    })`

Comment: i will go with the second one i think it will be easier to retrieve each value if it is stand alone like the second one

Comment: Sir one question i want to push the value of these data in `studentdata.push({
            $quarters.eq($td.index()).find('span').text().trim(): $td.parent().find('td:first-child span').text().trim()
            });`
But i get error in line `$quarters.eq($td.index()).find('span').text().trim(): $td.parent().find('td:first-child span').text().trim()`
How can do it in a way it would look like `1st Quarter : Joe Smith` it will be easy like this so i can just get it value like studentdata['1st Quarter'] then it will give me names of student with check on first quarter

Comment: Sir please check update my question is how can i put the variable in quarter to be in the label si that i get `valueToPush.push({
        quarter.eq($td.index()).find('span').text().trim(): $td.parent().find('td:first-child span').text().trim()
    });` so i can get the Quarter number and Student name to be in one line

Answer (score 1):

You can initially track each checkbox click and store them in an array. Later, while clicking the button you can retrieve the Student names and the quarters they appeared in directly. Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/507m8583/3/)

```
var arrObj = {};

$("input[type='checkbox']").click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        var studentName = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first span').html();
        var quarterIndex = $(this).closest('td').index();
        var quarterName = $(this).closest('table').find('tr:first td:eq('+parseInt(quarterIndex)+')').find('span').html();
        if(arrObj[studentName]) {
            arrObj[studentName].push(quarterName);
        } else {
            arrObj[studentName] = [];
            arrObj[studentName].push(quarterName);
        }
    }
});

$(document).on('click', '#check', function() {

    for( var key in arrObj) {
        alert(key+" appeard in: "+arrObj[key]);
    }
});
```

Comment: nice and clean others can use it